# Error in extending an abstract class

Tags: java

I was just experimenting with abstract classes and bumped into an error.

I have one class as:

```
public abstract class C {
    String aname;
    int aid;

    public C(String s, int n) {
        aname = s;
        aid = n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Now, another class extends it as follows:

```
public class D extends C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

However, it gives the following error:

```
error: constructor C in class C cannot be applied to given types;
public class D extends C {
       ^
  required: String,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Do note that I chose not to have any abstract methods yet.

Comment: Since you only have a constructor with 2 parameters `C(String s, int n)`, Java is complaining that it needs `D` to pass those parameters to its superclass (`C`)

Comment: How do I fix it mate? I mean without adding a new constructor with no paremeters.

Comment: Like if it only has the constructor that's been provided. How do I extend it?

Comment: Check manouti's answer on what you need to include/remove

Answer (score 1):

Since class `D` does not define any constructor, the compiler automatically creates a *default* no-argument constructor for it. However, this constructor implicitly calls the no-argument constructor of the base class `C`, which is not defined -- a no-argument constructor exists if you explicitly define one or if you don't define any constructor. To solve it, you can either define a no-arg constructor for `C`:

```
public C() {

}
```

or you can define a constructor in `D` that has the same parameters as that of the parent class:

```
public D(String s, int n) {
    super(s, n);
}
```

Comment: Excellent point. My confidence has grown now.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `abstract` classes and methods, and everything to do with the fact that you don't have a constructor declared in `D`.

You have only one constructor in `C`, and it takes 2 arguments.  You did not declare a constructor in `D`, so Java implicitly inserts a [no-arg, default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).  It calls the superclass's default (no-arg) constructor, but that doesn't exist in `C`.

You must explicitly create a `D` constructor that calls `C`'s 2-arg constructor or supply a no-arg constructor in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameterized constructor only in the abstract class. Try to have explicit default constructor or override the one in child.